# IMAP: java, how to determine a folder has been renamed or moved?

Tags: java, directory, jakarta-mail, imap

We use java mail api with an imap account. Suppose we have an empty folder **a** and then rename it to **b** on outlook. The folder has fullname **inbox.a** and then **inbox.b**.
Or we move the folder to inbox.c for example, it becomes **inbox.c.a**.

How can we determine for example rename action (a to b), more clearly how can be distinguish:

1. a was renamed to b or
2. a was deleted and totally different folder b was generated

Do we have to use the messages in the folders to help whether it was a real rename or delete/create action?

In java, when i debug IMAPFolder instance, the only value i can keep reference is the UIDValidty number? Can i rely on it? As i know it can be changed by the mail server on some occurances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a standard way. Some servers have a non-standard extension to relieve that (`status x-guid`), but gmail is the world's biggest IMAP server and does not implement x-guid.

This is a problem. Fortunately it doesn't happen very often.

Two different, independent mailboxes can have the same uidvalidity. I don't know how commonly that happens.